# How to call class A's method 1 which invokes class B's method 2 in C++?

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding, wrapper, composition

I have a base class A and hope to create a class B with very similar functionality. I want class B to have a function to call class A's func1(), but when calling it, the func2() is replaced/over-rided by class B's func2(). My goal is to avoid repeated code and not modify class A. The inheritance implementation below does not work. Should I use inheritance here? How can I achieve my goal?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    void func1() {
        func2();
        cout << "class A fun1" << endl;
    }
private:
    void func2() {
        cout << "class A fun2" << endl;
    }
};

class B : A{
public:
    void func3() {
        func1();
        cout << "class B fun3" << endl;
    }
private:
    void func2() {
        cout << "class B fun2" << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    B b;
    b.func3();
    return 0;
}
```

The current output is:

```
class A fun2
class A fun1
class B fun3
```

But what I want is:

```
class B fun2
class A fun1
class B fun3
```

Comment: You can't without modifying `class A`, since the call to `A::func2` inside `A::func1`  is already established as non-virtual. You need to make it `virtual func2` in `class A` and `func2 override` in `class B`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `virtual` function for that. When a function is declared as `virtual`, the compiler only uses the implementation of the virtual function that is present in the derived class.

The function in the base class cannot be used directly from the base class. As in, if you create an object for the class `A`, you won’t be able to call `func2()` if it’s declared as virtual.

**Note**: You'll be able to call the virtual function from the derived class even though the virtual function definition is not present in the derived class (because it'll anyways be inherited and you'll be calling the inherited copy of the virtual function).

Hope it helps. Happy coding! :)